# Black Screen after suspend or closing lid Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, screen, mate

I’m new here and I’m new in the Ubuntu world. I’m sorry if the problem I’m going to show you is a newbie problem. And I’m sorry for my bad english, too.

BTW, I recently installed Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS x64 as a single OS on my MacBook Air (Late 2010 with Intel Core2Duo, 1,86 GHzx2 and 2Gb of RAM), and I have a problem with the backlight when I suspend it or when I close the lid:

if I try to wake up it or open the lid, the screen remains black, but I know the PC is working, because I hear the sound when I press a key.
I hope you understood me and someone could help me.